# MobilePush SDK & Progressive Web Apps (PWA)

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush

My question is rather simple, and I can't find anything on it in the SDK documentation.

Can the current disposition of the MobilePush SDK be integrated in Progressive Web Apps (PWA)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PWA Apps are basically Websites running on modern browsers. Push notifications in PWAs context are simply Browser notifications and for the moment MobilePush doesn't support Web notifications.

The MobilePush SDK only supports :

- iOS native code -> https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/
- Android native code -> https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/
- Hybrid with Cordova plugin -> https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin
- Hybrid with ReactNative plugin -> https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk